# Need help importing a sql database for a wordpress local hosted with MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mamp

Hello beautiful people of stackoverflow. I am trying to import a database in phpmyadmin using mamp (NOT PRO VERSION). After i succesfully imported the database after modifying the maximum file size (cause noob yeahh) i modified the wp-config.php file to fit my database where i imported the sql file for every little thing. Now after all that - When i try to connect to localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-admin or any other link from the locally hosted wordpress my page is refreshed and that's it. I tried to change the OPCache in php.ini file that i am using with these values:

```
[OPcache]
;zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/opcache.so"
;  opcache.memory_consumption=128
;  opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
;  opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
;  opcache.revalidate_freq=60
;  opcache.fast_shutdown=1
;  opcache.enable_cli=1
```

But this is not working. Has anyone encountered this or have any idea what I can do to make it work ?

Comment: Did your wordpress site ever work at all/were you ever able to see any page? Are you sure that you didn't accidentally leave out a quote mark when you edited the wordpress site? Now that you have the database imported, what happens if you changed your settings back the way they were before? Are you sure that the URL you typed is the URL of the website? Are there any configuration steps on the wordpress folder itself you missed inside your MAMP?

Comment: First i installed wordpress without anything. Simple and clean. After i copy paste my site folder over it and edit the wp-config and imported the database sql in phpmyadmin. I even edited the table prefix everything.

Comment: Did any files get left inside when you copy-pasted your new folder? If you can't figure it out, it may be more time-efficient to wipe the folder and start over again from scratch, going very slowly and carefully through your steps. I found some online tutorials for you: [SkillCrush](https://skillcrush.com/2015/04/14/install-wordpress-mac/), [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP), [WPMudev](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/develop-wordpress-locally-mamp/)

Comment: When i copy paste the folder i renamed the new folder wordpress and replace it once i paste it.

Comment: Are you sure that you set your document root in MAMP correctly for your wordpress site? See step 5 [SkillCrush](https://skillcrush.com/2015/04/14/install-wordpress-mac/)

Comment: Looks ok i can't understand why this problem persist... I

Comment: If you can't find someone to help you in a day or two my advice would be to start again from scratch using one of the tutorials and to go super slowly. For every step, perform additional checks. For example, after the step where you start running your MAMP, are you able to view any pages on MAMP including PHPMyAdmin? Going slowly like this will help you to determine if there are other problems that you are having that the tutorial didn't mention.

Comment: The PHPMyAdmin works fine only when i access wordpress folder is a problem

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress locks down it's url that it loads from.  For example in your sql file you downloaded it probably has a several locations that reference your current website, let's call it www.publishedwebsite.com.  So when you try to load the page it tries to redirect you to that site.  Try replacing all references to your website (www.publishedwebsite.com) in the .sql file to your local installation (localhost:8888/wordpress/), then re-import your database.

Also try xampp, unless you prefer MAMP already: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html